# How to avoid click behind(action bar) context action bar CAB?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-actionbar, contextual-action-bar

I have a ListView that shows a CAB using `listView.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);` and `listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(multiChoiceModeListener);` and when the CAB is shown, I can click on action bar option buttons like the scan barcode here:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Possible make the toolbar or actionbar setEnables(false).  Then set it enabled after it is dismissed.

Comment: That could be a workaround, but the header image is clickable too and I still having the same problem with it, I can disable it too, but I think is not usable because the header still visible for the user. I want to understand why the action bar allows me interact with it. Thanks.

Comment: Good question. I am not entirely sure why it would do that